# autocomplete not updating options but new array is available in hits property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, algolia

```
import { Highlight, connectAutoComplete } from 'react-instantsearch-dom';
import AutoSuggest from 'react-autosuggest';
import Autocomplete, { createFilterOptions } from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

class AutoCompleteuix extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    hits: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
    currentRefinement: PropTypes.string.isRequired, };

  state = {
    value: this.props.currentRefinement,
  };

  onChange = (_, { newValue }) => {
    if (!newValue) {
      this.props.onSuggestionCleared();
    }

    this.setState({
      value: newValue,
    });
  };

  onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
    this.props.refine(value);
  };

  onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
    this.props.refine();
  };

  render() {
    const { hits, onSuggestionSelected } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state;
    const inputProps = {
      onChange: this.onChange,
    };

    return (
        <Autocomplete
        options={hits}
        getOptionLabel={(hits) => hits.ROMAN} 
        onInputChange = {(ev,obj,val) => this.props.refine(obj) }
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="search for a Word" variant="outlined"/> }
        value
      />
    );
  }
}

export default connectAutoComplete(AutoCompleteuix);
```

hits has the options with are being passed into options but my problem is the dropdown is not updated as per the latest value but the hits have all the updated values.
im tryign to use the algolia search which give the values of hit coming from another component